# JsonSerializer.Deserialize can't inferred the usage

Tags: c#, .net-core, jsonserializer

if I pass a string just to the method, the VS2019 give error that the usage can't be inferred.

if I write like this

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize(text);
JsonSerializer.Deserialize(text.AsSpan());
```

both are giving the same error. as a string is convertible to the span.

but as mentioned in the [Deserialize Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize_System_String_System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_), the none generic type should work. but what I'm getting in here is the generic type.

[Json Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1pbCJR)

I tried to google but didn't lead to any result.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods that you highlighted take one type parameter, which is the type of C# object that holds deserialized data. You need to either specify the type parameter, or use an overload that takes type of the object as the second parameter:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Data
    {
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Enabled.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String json = "{ \"Enabled\" : true }";
            // Using 2 different overload to deserialize data.
            Data data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            var data2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(Data));
            Console.WriteLine(data2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the right method, in order to use the non generic one you need to specify the Type in the second argument.

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize(text, typeof(object));
```